# Using both exists and simple value checking in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM following f WHERE f.from = 2 AND f.to = p.uid
    )
    OR p.uid = 2
```

I want it to return all records from `posts` where `following` has a record `WHERE f.from = 2 AND f.to = p.uid` as well as all records where `p.uid = 2`.

If I have the exists check first, only the records that match the exists return. If I swap them around only the records that match `p.uid = 2` return.

Comment: Provide some sample data along with the desired output.

Comment: I've checked your queries and it's seems that both versions work fine regardless of the order of conditions in the where clause, please take a look at this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b098/3 both queries return exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count instead:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  posts p 
WHERE
  (SELECT count(*) FROM following f WHERE f.from = 2 AND f.to = p.uid) > 0 
  OR p.uid = 2
```

What do you think?

Comment: This has the same issue as the previous attempt. The former statement takes priority for some reason.

Comment: EXISTS is faster that COUNT(*), read this article: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/exists-vs-count

Answer (score 0):

Another approch:

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM POSTS P 
LEFT JOIN FOLLOWING F ON F.to=P.uid
WHERE P.uid=2 OR F.from=2
```

You Can add `distinct` in the select clause if needed